# cannot write to certain directory using CentOS distro

Tags: php, centos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best linux permissions to use for my website?](https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-are-the-best-linux-permissions-to-use-for-my-website)

I have a script that will generate an image then upload it in a certain directory. The script works fine, however uploading it in the CentOS server, it won't work anymore. By debugging, I have found out that this is a permission denied issue. I am forced to `chmod -R 777 certain_directory` to make it work.

I am not convince with this, I can't set the directory ownership to `www-data` I'm used to when I am using Debian. Any workaround for this?

Comment: `www-data` is a debian-ism, CentOS and other RH-type distros use a different username for their webserver, but I don't know what it is (`apache`?).

Answer (score 1):

The user you are using to upload the image to the **certain_directory** should have write permission on the directory you are uploading to. Now for example the user is jon then you can change the directory permission by

`chown jon:jon certain_directory`.

If you do not want to change the ownership to jon user then add jon in user's group by editing the /etc/group and change the permission of the group by using the command

`chmod 764 certain_directory`.

Here 6 means user can read and write to **certain_directory**