# How can I make my public directory writable by nginx and user?

Tags: nginx, chown

I have my WordPress site newly hosted on a small Linux box with Nginx. Nginx runs as the user www-data just like apache, so I have the entire public_html directory owned by www-data so that WordPress can upload media files, install new plugins, etc.

My question is how can I setup the public_html directory so that a user logged in via SFTP can upload or edit files? I tried doing

```
chown -R myUserName:www-data public_html
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean?

Comment: It still wasn't writable by the server anymore, only the user.

Comment: You might want to look at the answers for [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-are-the-best-linux-permissions-to-use-for-my-website).

Answer (score 1):

One thing is setting the owner and group - but you need to define whether or not the user and/or group can write.

This will do what you are asking

```
find /path/to/public_html -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find /path/to/public_html -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

**However, you don't want your webserver to be able to write to everything on a Wordpress installation.**

You want to figure out exactly what directories you need to be writable by reading the [Wordpress hardening guide](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/)

If you do not do this, rest assured that your site will be hacked at some point. Not necessarily defaced or changed, but attackers often just use a little space on your site to store a phishing page - which can be a pain to fix.

Comment: If the server is not writable to the WordPress install directory, then automatic updates will never work. I had already set the permissions on file, but this changes nothing.

Comment: Those commands will set all files and folders to be writable by user and group. And the group is www-data as you set with your chown, thus giving www-data write access to the files.