# User permissions on web server

Tags: linux, file-permissions, cms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best linux permissions to use for my website?](https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-are-the-best-linux-permissions-to-use-for-my-website)

I have allot of users  which install joomla, wordpress, drupal and other CMS things on their websites ( linux server). Usually they get problem with write permissions when they want to install additional modules or plugins.  What they do in this case is to automatically set 777 on their directories and  they leave it like that. Of course that causes problems to me from security perspective.

Don't know how to formulate this questions correctly but  hopefully someone will understand. 
what would be the best default  permissions to give to users so they  would not get such errors and then change everything to 777?  Is there any option, when CMS's are in question, which would prevent problems with write permissions and by that users wouldn't  need to put everything to 777.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

755 is pretty usual but it also depends on the server environment. Have a read through: http://www.anchor.com.au/blog/2012/09/the-chmod-777-trap-how-and-why-to-avoid-it/