# Allow WordPress to Update on Local Apache2 Install

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, wordpress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best linux permissions to use for my website?](https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-are-the-best-linux-permissions-to-use-for-my-website)

I'm having an issue that I can't seem to find an answer for, i've already scoured Google & SF and haven't found an answer, i've fixed this before by changing ownership, but i'm not sure how I did it in the past.

I am doing my WordPress development in a Kubuntu VM, where I have a LAMP setup (installed through tasksel for ease of installation). When I go to try to update/install any plugins (or presumably themes), it does the thing that it asks for the FTP credentials.

All of my production servers run NGINX, so this isn't a huge deal as I know how to set up an LEMP environment to run all of the WP functionality that I need.

I also changed ownership before of the /var/www directory to me (admin user), so I didn't have to type 'sudo' every time that I edited a file, as that is an unnecessary inconvenience.

I'm not completely sure how to fix this, and would REALLY appreciate everyone's help on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If your production server runs nginx, perhaps you should run nginx on your development server as well.

Comment: It really makes no difference for WordPress's purposes, and it takes significantly longer to set up NGINX that the "tasksel" command. Which is why I use apache2 on my local environment, then I move to my NGINX QA environment. Also, I dont think anything there answers my qustion, I am fine with WP permissions, I think it has to do with groups and who apache is running as.

Comment: I figured it out

`sudo chown www-data mysite`

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to give the Apache user access to the Wordpress install's directory so it can write to it.

```
sudo chown www-data (your site dir)
```

I had the same issue recently and this was the fix.

EDIT: Doh, you've answered your own question already :)

Comment: Yea, Thanks for your help though! I appreciate the answer (confirming I did it right)