# Can groups have write access when owners don't?

Tags: linux, permissions

I am following a [serverfault response](https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-are-the-best-linux-permissions-to-use-for-my-website) (skip to "You can have your cake and eat it too") about website permissions, and I can't get folder permissions 570 to work as expected. I have verified I'm a member of the group and permissions are 570, but I can't even access the directory.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
mkdir newfolder
chown lesseruser newfolder
chgrp greaterusers newfolder
chmod 570 newfolder
```

I am a member of greaterusers (verified in /etc/group) and I cannot access the directory.

Output ll:
dr-xrwx---  2  lesseruser  greaterusers

Will wonders never cease. I just rebooted the server and everything works as expected. Strange, but for sure I'll reboot the next time before posting. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What error you are getting while trying to access ?

Comment: Also, what's the location where you created this test directory ?

Comment: Does the `group` command show that this user is also in greatusers? Also please confirm that the command `id` also shows the group greatusers too.

Comment: The directory is in /var/www/. The id command shows that the user is a member of the group.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more info? I'm able to successfully do what I think you explained in the question:

```
% groups
saml tmux vboxusers jupiter

% pwd
/home/saml/adir

% ls -la
total 24
dr-xrwx---    2 root saml  4096 Jan 12 22:46 .
drwx------. 214 saml saml 20480 Jan 12 22:48 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 saml saml     0 Jan 12 22:46 afile1
-rw-r--r--    1 saml saml     0 Jan 12 22:46 afile2
```

**NOTE:** I'm on `Fedora 14` with a `ext4` filesystem.

Comment: I replied with an edit.