# Add my User to www-data group on fedora?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, http, fedora

So I am setting up a localhost for web development on my Fedora 20 desktop.  I have installed httpd and so forth...

The issue I have is adding my user to the /var/www and to /var/www/html. I looked into /etc/group and did not see a www-data group nor a http group, but I did see an apache group.

But when I ls -alF /var:

```
    drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root 4096 Mar  3 09:46 www/
```

And /var/www:

```
    drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 4096 Oct 14 21:17 html/
```

So they are owned by the root group.  How would you recommend setting up these folders so that my user has access to these folders for web development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Fedora, `/var/www` is used for the default web site, which shows the test page when someone hits your web site with its direct IP address or a hostname for which no virtual host is configured. Since this directory is managed by the packaging system, it's [best practice](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#SRVDATAFORSERVICESPROVIDEDBYSYSTEM) to place *your own* web sites in directories under `/srv/www` (which you should create) and set their ownership and permissions to [whatever is appropriate for your particular scenario](https://serverfault.com/q/357108/126632).