# AWS ec2-user permission denied

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have my [Apache HTTP server on Amazon Linux AMI](http://kabestany.com.pl/). I am trying to install a Prestashop on my root directory subfolder as an ec2-user via SSH.

```
cd /var/www/html
```

but when I tried to create a directory

```
mkdir prestashoptest
```

I always get this error

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘prestashoptest’: Permission denied
```

What should I do? How can I have a full permission?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What permissions should my website files/folders have on a Linux webserver?](http://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver)

Comment: RTFM  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AmazonLinuxAMIBasics.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `sudo` command or `sudo su` for root access in Amazon ssh.

Try

```
sudo mkdir prestashoptest
```

or use `sudo su` followed by the password for `ec2-user` and perform the simply `mkdir`

Answer (score 2):

You don't have permission to create this directory. You have many possibilities to solve that, but anyways you need to get root access (either by the `sudo bash` or by the `su` commands, or by ssh-ing into them with root. You need the root password for all of them.)

The best were to create the directory for your project in `/var/www/html` with the `mkdir /var/www/html/myprojectname` command, and then make your user account to the owner of this directory (`chown youruser:youruser /var/www/html/myproject`). From that point, you will be able to edit this directory with your own user account.

Of course you could do everything as root as well, but a professional system administrator never did such thing.