# From where should I serve the vhosts

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I used to create a user called company_xyz and serve the httpdocs file from
`/home/company_xyz/web/project1/public` and so on for each different project. Is there a guideline or best practice on where to serve the vhosts files, I saw few using `/var/www/vhosts/projectx` with the owner and group set to apache. Does it matter, or is it just a matter of personal preference?

Comment: There is no right way for this. You can put them wherever you want. I like to put them in `/var/vhosts`. The folder belongs to root. The vhost folder belongs to the webserver user if the app needs write permissions otherwise it belongs to root.

Answer (score 1):

Apache itself simply follows whatever values you configure for the source of content e.g. in the `DocumentRoot` or `Alias` directive.  Except for a few obviously bad locations (`/root` or `/tmp` come to mind) as long as your configuration  is correct, any directory suffices.

There are a number of good answers under the following question as well: [what permissions for my website](https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver)

Traditionally personal homepages are served from the users `~/public_html` folder in their home directory.

For some Linux distributions `/var/www` has become the "*default location*" for websites (that mainly implies that there suitable SELinux or AppArmor default policies have been applied).

If you have multiple users, each uploading their own website, or project, then you may at least benefit from a scheme that hosts the site content within their home directory. That at least allows uploading combined with a chroot jail and prevents your user from easily browsing the complete file system. That typically will require the sysadmin setting up the site before it becomes available.