# Give root privileges to an user just for a specific directory

Tags: linux, permissions

I have have a web server running on my machine and I would like to give the 2 users, *misterX* and *misterY*, root privileges for the directory `/var/www` so that they can also edit the files that are being created by other users and/or scripts.

Comment: you cannot do this. you are probably looking for containers. like ovz ot lxc.

Comment: They don't necessarily need root, they need correct file system permissions. Either add those users to the groups owning those files. Alternatively investigate POSIX or extended ACL's which you can use to give more granular permissions than the traditional user,group,other permissions.

Comment: You may also find some inspiration in [what permissions should my website files folders have](http://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need *root* permissions - you need group permissions. For example if the group is www-data, do something along the lines of `usermod -a -G www-data misterX` and make sure the files are group-writable.

Comment: Thanks for helping, just a little addition: I had to use the command `usermod -a -G www-data misterX` since the user is already existing. Maybe someone will find it useful.

Comment: Thanks for the input - I have edited my answer accordingly