# WordPress can't move files (Nginx, HHVM)

Tags: nginx, permissions, wordpress

I have a WordPress setup using HHVM & NGINX on Ubuntu 14.04 that can't moves files when uploaded.

Nginx is running as www-data.

Files are all owned by deploy:deploy. Where www-data is a member of deploy & deploy is a member of www-data as well.

If files are set to 777 upload works as expected. 775 is giving an error.  Leads me to believe it is a permissions error.

Any idea what I've done wrong setting up groups and users?

Comment: "Is giving an error" means exactly what? Web servers usually give helpful log file entries for cases like this.

Comment: Did you restart the HHVM daemon after changing the user groups ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What permissions should my website files/folders have on a Linux webserver?](http://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver)

Answer (score -1):

I also wrestled with this problem. Here's a basic solution to help point you in the right direction:

---

**Step 1:** find the default root folder of your web server

- For example `/var/www`

**Step 2:** give the user www-data full ownership of web server folder. (*Use `-R` to make change recursive.*)

- `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/webserver/root`

**Step 3:** restart NGINX

- `sudo service nginx restart`

---

Note: The above will solve your problem; though it exposes your server stack to number of potential vulnerabilities. Please check the links below for further info:

#### File Permissions

I strongly suggest you set permissions back to 755, to avoid any unnecessary security issues. Check out the Wordpress codex info on file permissions.

- link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#File_Permissions

#### Linux permissions

Also, check the link below for further info on setting up users and groups. It provides a good breakdown of Linux permissions, privilege separation etc. Should cover all your needs...

- Link: https://serverfault.com/a/357109/293491

---

You're definitely looking in the right area, the answer is much closer than you might think!

Comment: In principle I fully agree with you. That being said, Stewart's question is related to permissions and read/write errors with `Wordpress` running on `NGINX`. My answer shows a basic solution, but also refers to the Wordpress documentation on security; as well as a serverfault answer, that clearly explains `server`, `group` and `user` permissions for a secure stack running on `Ubuntu` or other `Debian-based` Linux distributions. I'll edit my answer to reflect this, thanks for pointing this out.