# Custom root folder for apache giving access denied

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu

I just installed ubuntu desktop (because I figured server will be too much for me, and apparently I was right) and I'm trying to configure my apache web server but unfortunately it has nothing to do with the way I'm used to configuring it on windows.

I installed the package `lamp-server^` which supposedly packs php and mysql as well but I haven't even got to those yet.

After I installed the package and went to `http://localhost` I saw the default welcoming page, so far so good. However I want to move the root folder from `/var/www/html` to `/home/user/www/html` since I didn't really know how much space to give these partitions and I gave `home` significantly more space. To do this I would have to edit `httpd.conf` but there is no such file on the system. After a brief research I found that I have to edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` which is a virtual server, I guess. So I edited it like so

```
ServerName localhost
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /home/user/www/html
```

Not only am I continuing to get this annoying message

> AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

Additionally I'm getting 403 access denied when I try to access `http://localhost`

I have been looking for solutions on the web as well as on the lamp page but I just can't seem to get things right, it's very exhausting..

Comment: I can't find any package named lamp-server or lamp- anything in Ubuntu. ?

Comment: @AndrewSchulman https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

Comment: Hm - first I've ever seen of the caret thing.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/211912/whats-the-caret-mean-in-apt-get

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, try setting `ServerName localhost` in the main server context, that is, outside of a VirtualHost container.  To do that, put the directive in a file e.g. /etc/apache2/conf-available/servername.conf, then run `a2enconf servername` to enable it, and restart apache with `service apache2 restart`.

As for the 403 error, /home/user/www/html probably isn't readable by the www-data user.  To test that, try setting `chmod a+rx /home /home/user /home/user/www /home/user/www/html`, and see if the 403 goes away.  But note that these are broader permissions than you normally want to set.  For a more permanent set of permissions for apache, see [What permissions should my website files/folders have on a Linux webserver?](https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver/357109#357109)