# Created virtual users for vsftpd, now how to make nginx access their home directories?

Tags: nginx, permissions, vsftpd

I installed and setup `vsftpd` with virtual users, and each one of them has folder in `/home/vftp`. The ownership of `/home/vftp` is `ftp:ftp`.

When I point a subdomain to open with `nginx` from one of those folders - I get `403 Forbidden`.

What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What permissions should my website files/folders have on a Linux webserver?](http://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver)

Comment: Oh, I'm very stupid :D ... now I tried to request a specific file and had no problems ... and the reason I got `403: Forbidden` is because the directory listing was not enabled. The stuff is working fine :) ... my bad ... sorry ...