# VPS server web permissions Ubuntu Linux setup for LAMP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, web

Okay, So basically my question is this. My web files are like this var/www/public_html/index.html When I upload files and then go to correct domain on the internet I get "Forbidden You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server." and then it gives "
Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) Server at domain.com Port 443"

I know there might be an answer somewhere similar but I seriously can not find proper answer for me because ive trid chmod and all that stuff and nothing seems to work. Im grateful if you can give me an answer Thanks.

Comment: Please show error_log.

Comment: I dont know how to view that

Comment: Check it in `/var/log/apache/error_log`

Comment: Fri Aug 11 09:00:43.833843 2017] [core:error] [pid 15448] (13)Permission denied:  file permissions deny server access: /var/www/example.com/public_html/images/9.png, referer: https://example.com/

Comment: [Detailed answer](https://serverfault.com/a/357109/392131) on how to fix web server file permissions. Basically, you need to be sure that your Apache user has directory traversal rights to all parent directories (`chmod +x`) and read access to the files (`chmod +r`).

Comment: I have made permission changes like this but it doesnt even show up on the web. like shouldnt my html files and dirctories be viewable on web

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out myself. if this ever happens to you just do this in root

sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/

fixed.

Comment: This may cause other issues, so be sure you understand what this does.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what this does. other then fix the above issue. I'm 20 just set up VPS and made virtual host been firing off commands right and left. No idea what im doing but everyone makes things so complicated its ridiculous there should just be one button that sets it all up perfect and secure

Comment: "No idea what I'm doing" plus `sudo` can end very badly.

Comment: I believe it... its my server though... worst thing i have to erase the whole thing and start over from scratch.. i got good back ups. Setting up VPS and doing all this purely to educate myself on how to work a system and learn command line.