# Nginx displaying failed (13: Permission denied) when trying to access new site

Tags: linux, nginx, centos, web-server

I am trying to set up my own web server to learn a bit more about server admin.

I have decided that I want to serve each sites files from a `public_html` folder inside the users /home directory.

I have installed Nginx, edited the nginx.conf and changed the username / group to nginx.

I have added a new user for the new site and changed the vhosts file to look like so;

```
server {
    listen         80;
    listen         [::]:80;
    server_name    website.com www.website.com;
    root           /home/website/public_html;
    index          index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

But when I try and get to the site, it returns a 404 Not Found.

When I check the error log, I am seeing the following errors;

```
2019/01/02 19:49:45 [crit] 18248#0: *1 stat() "/home/website/public_html/" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

Any chance someone has come across this before and could tell me how to handle it?

I have had a look around and saw some posts about getenforce, but when i run it, it says `Disabled`.

I am using CentOS7 if that makes any difference.

Cheers,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What permissions should my website files/folders have on a Linux webserver?](https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver)

Comment: @JennyD .. Im using nginx not Apache

Comment: You need the same basic set of permissions regardless of which webserver you're running. Obviously you need to replace the username `apache` with whatever username nginx is running under.

Comment: No, that didn't work ... Im still getting the exact same errors

Comment: Don't serve web sites from user home directories, for a wide variety of reasons.

Comment: Is `selinux` enabled?

Answer (score 12):

Following the guide from this [website](https://caradede.blogspot.com/2017/12/how-to-solve-13-permission-denied.html) did it for me (as root):

```sh
setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs 1
setenforce 0
systemctl restart nginx
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Answer (score 6):

A good way to debug such nginx errors is by checking the logs and using `namei` to check whether nginx has access to all ancestor folders.

Consider `/static/vendor.js` gives a `HTTP 403` due to this configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /static/ {
    alias /home/ubuntu/bla/front/dist/;
    }
}
```

First check out nginx access logs, in ubuntu it's here:

`tail /var/log/nginx/error.log`

Mine says:

```
2023/07/25 11:52:05 [error] 15138#15138: *3 open() "/home/ubuntu/bla/front/dist/vendor.js" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 145.90.169.214, server: , request: "GET /static/vendor.js HTTP/1.1", host: "129.125.55.156
```

I notice the file `/home/ubuntu/bla/front/dist/vendor.js` does exist, so I check whether `www-data` (nginx user) can access it:

`sudo -u www-data namei /home/ubuntu/bla/front/dist/vendor.js`

```
f: /home/ubuntu/bla/front/dist/vendor.js
 d /
 d home
 d ubuntu
   bla - Permission denied
```

Apparently the `bla` folder can't be accessed, this is likely due to not having `rx` rights on the `ubuntu` folder. That is, if the parent can't be read, the child is invisible. I'll fix this using `setfacl`, a way to give fine-grained ACL permissions without changing the user and group of a file.

`sudo setfacl -m g:www-data:rx /home/ubuntu/`

And now:

`sudo -u www-data namei /home/ubuntu/bla/front/dist/vendor.js`

```
f: /home/ubuntu/bla/front/dist/vendor.js
 d /
 d home
 d ubuntu
 d bla
 d front
 d dist
 - vendor.js
```

The file is accessible by `www-data`, and also nginx's `403` disappeared.

Comment: You deserve some kind of prize for being the only person I found on the whole internet who intelligently suggested using `namei` to test the permissions on a certain file using a certain user, which shows exactly where the issue is. THANK YOU kind stranger.

Comment: @DelPiero Glad to hear it helped you. It's not entirely altruistic though. As a data scientist (or whatever I'm called these days) certain Linux and nginx knowledge tends to get lost, and I'll be happy to read my own answer as a refresher.

Answer (score 2):

It is your home directory permission that is denying access to nginx.

Try:

```
ls -ld /home/website
```

then

```
setfacl -R -m u:nginx:rwx /home/website
```

Or

```
chown -R nginx:nginx /home/website
chmod 655 /home/website
```

Comment: default user for nginx is www-data so it's likely going to need to be ```sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/website```

Comment: @samayres1992 user created for centos/rhel is 'nginx'

Comment: @TedKhi Samayres is right though.  Unless you also explain that you need to change the default user that nginx runs as by updating `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` to change the `user www-data` line to read `user nginx` instead, then the above would not work (unless they had already done that).

Comment: worked for me. I had to do 777 instead of 655. Thanks

Comment: @RenilBabu Using 777 is a bad idea - that means ANYONE can write to you directory. Use 755 instead

Answer (score 2):

Better fix: ls -Z myFile.js will show the SELinux context:
-rw-r--r--. nginx nginx unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 myFile.js
Then, use chcon -v --type=httpd_sys_content_t myFile to change the SELinux content.
I did it with Andrew Richard Miller's answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25774999/nginx-stat-failed-13-permission-denied#comment84000833_30897591

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to set the `/home/user/public_html` permissions to 755. By default, it was being created with 751 permissions. This was blocking the nginx user from being able to 'read' it. Certain web hosting panels like VestaCP, CPanel, and others may inadvertently do this when adding a new site through their interface.

Solution:
`sudo chmod 755 ~/public_html` (adjust path to your public_html folder)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was fixed (from [this blog](https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-nginx-plus-with-selinux/)) by running the command: `semanage permissive -a httpd_t` and restarting NGINX service.

Comment: After several tries, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The {13: permission denied} error most likely due to the SElinux policy rules.
check `sudo sestatus`
if it SELinux status:enabled then you need to find out which context is blocked by SElinux.
most likely it is `httpd_t`
you can identify this by running `ps axZ | grep httpd` this command.
It shows which context label is given to the nginx process.
and to add it in permissive, execute this command `sudo semanage permissive -a httpd_t`.
then restart nginx and app server.