# open() "/var/lib/nginx/cache/fastcgi/3/d0/bce7bdb8e2c388c7675c97c7324efd03" failed (13: Permission denied)

Tags: nginx, permissions, proxy, cache, fastcgi

I am trying to add **Caching** for **Proxy** & **FastCGI** but once i try to view any page on the site it fails with **500 Internal Server Error** and when i tried searching my logs for any errors i found that **nginx** can't access the cache folder:

**FastCGI**: `2023/10/29 10:53:30 [crit] 591459#591459: *1 open() "/var/lib/nginx/cache/fastcgi/3/d0/bce7bdb8e2c388c7675c97c7324efd03" failed (13: Permission denied), client: ::1, server: localhost, request: "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"`

**Proxy**: `2023/10/29 10:52:25 [crit] 591351#591351: *1 open() "/var/lib/nginx/cache/expressjs/9/f3/f3bfeb3387c38d7a557be4d864d67f39" failed (13: Permission denied), client: ::1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"`

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**:

```
http {
    proxy_cache_path /var/lib/nginx/cache/expressjs  levels=1:2 keys_zone=expressjs-cache:30m max_size=192m;
    fastcgi_cache_path /var/lib/nginx/cache/fastcgi  levels=1:2 keys_zone=php-cache:30m max_size=192m;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/expressjs.conf**:

```
location ~ ^/dev {
    ### ........
    proxy_cache expressjs-cache;
    proxy_cache_key $host$request_uri;
    proxy_cache_valid any 10m;
    proxy_cache_valid 401 5s;
    proxy_cache_valid 403 5s;
    proxy_cache_valid 404 5s;
    proxy_cache_valid 500 5s;
    proxy_cache_valid 501 5s;
    proxy_cache_valid 502 5s;
    proxy_cache_bypass 0;
    proxy_no_cache 0; # $http_upgrade
}
```

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/fastcgi.conf**:

```
location ~ ^/phpmyadmin {
    ### ........
    fastcgi_cache php-cache;
    fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme:$request_method~$host/$request_uri";
    fastcgi_cache_valid any 10m;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 401 5s;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 403 5s;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 404 5s;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 500 5s;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 501 5s;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 502 5s;
}
```

i tried to change permissions of **/var/lib/nginx/cache** to **read**&**write**:

```
sudo chmod -R u=rw /var/lib/nginx/cache
sudo chmod -R g=rw /var/lib/nginx/cache
sudo chmod -R o=rw /var/lib/nginx/cache
```

and owner of **/var/lib/nginx/cache** to root (and i tried **nginx** user too):

```
sudo chown -R root:root /var/lib/nginx/cache
```

EDIT:
i just found that **/var/lib/nginx/cache** should be given permission **exec** for **User**&**Group**&**Other**:

```
sudo chmod -R u=rwx /var/lib/nginx/cache
sudo chmod -R g=rwx /var/lib/nginx/cache
sudo chmod -R o=rwx /var/lib/nginx/cache
```

but once i restart **nginx**, it throws those errors again

Comment: Do the directories `expressjs` and `fastcgi` exist? Nginx will not create them for you.

Comment: yes it exists... @RichardSmith

Comment: Have you checked the permissions?

Comment: yes... it is applicable for read & write (as i mentioned in the question) @RichardSmith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error messages of type

```bash
open() "<file>" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

are usually related to SELinux or AppArmor.

You'll need to follow the documentation [Using NGINX and NGINX Plus with SELinux](https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-nginx-plus-with-selinux/) or adopt it for your needs.

**Similar Q&A**

- [Nginx displaying `failed (13: Permission denied)`](https://serverfault.com/questions/947301/)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but I am using apparmor not selinux...

Comment: If you are on in example Ubuntu or SuSE Linux, which are using AppArmor, you need to adopt the information provided for your system. Something like [How to create an AppArmor profile for Nginx on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-apparmor-profile-for-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) (ext. link).

Comment: zorono it does not matter, both restrict the access to the folder