# Shared hosting: how to prevent a user to see another's files but still have their files writable by Apache/PHP

Tags: linux, permissions, web-server, file-permissions, shared-hosting

I have read [What permissions should my website files/folders have on a Linux webserver?](https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver) and here is a linked question. Let's say:

- `/var/www/bobweb/` is owned by `bob:bob`
- `/var/www/eveweb/` is owned by `eve:eve`

and that each site has an Apache VirtualHost, linking to [bobweb.com](https://bobweb.com) and [eveweb.com](https://eveweb.com).

Each website needs to be writable by Apache (there is an image uploader on both websites), so I often read:

> "Just do `chgrp -R www-data /var/www/bobweb/`, idem for Eve, and that's all!"

This gives:

```
drwxrwx---  3 bob    www-data 4096 Jan  9 17:45 bobweb
drwxrwx---  5 eve    www-data 4096 Feb 26  2019 eveweb
```

This indeed prevents Bob to visit Eve's files from shell/SSH and vice-versa.

*But* it seems that Eve could write a PHP script (run by `www-data`) to read (or even modify) `/var/www/bobweb/wp-config.php` (thus stealing Bob's DB password!).

**Question: how to modify user+group ownerships and permissions to prevent Bob to read Eve's files and vice-versa, but still allow Apache+PHP to write data on these websites?**

(typical shared hosting situation)

Comment: Have you considered using a module like mod_suphp (not the old non-supported one but the one by lightsey on Github) which picks the uid from vhost settings and launches php scripts under defined user rather than a global one?

Another option would be to use php-fpm and launch multiple pools, then pass scripts from one vhost to that sock/port (and effectively again use uid rather than global account for executing php scripts)

Comment: @Miuku I was thinking there is a simple solution for this (the requirements here are very classic: typical for a shared hosting server) without installing new Apache modules, do you think it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

This can't fully be done with file permissions alone - you should look to the applications you are running to create jails. For PHP you can use "[open_basedir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)" on a per virtualhost basis.

You will also want something similar in your FTP server (you have not advised which server you are using but many/most have an appropriate directive).

Of-course if you are allowing cgis the entire problem space changes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For future reference, can you add a link to the solutions you recommend? PS: I don't use CGIs, only Apache 2.4+PHP+OpenSSH's SFTP (on a Debian).