# Correct permissions for WordPress directories and files on Ubuntu 20.04 with Apache

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, permissions, wordpress

My client's website is hosted at Digital Ocean and is running Ubuntu 20.04 with Apache. I have WordPress installed and running with some issues. The ability to upload or update plugins and themes is not working because of permission issues. I have been following the official WordPress security hardening [article](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/#file-permissions), but I believe some of the changes I have applied have caused the permission issues.

I have detailed all of the current permission settings below for reference. The user for this account is **callkneehill**.

Root WordPress directory (callkneehill.ca) and files found in /var/www:

- 755
- 644
- Owner and group are callkneehill

wp-admin and wp-include directories and files (recursively applied):

- 755
- 644
- Owner and group are callkneehill

wp-content directories and files (recursively applied):

- 755
- 644
- Owner is callkneehill
- Group is www-data

plugins and theme directories and files (recursively applied):

- 755
- 644
- Owner and group is callkneehill

With these permissions, WordPress informs me that FTP/SFTP needs to be used to upload/update plugins and themes. Before working with the hardening article, **www-data** was the sole owner and group for permissions within the WordPress root directory.

If I use **www-data** on the plugins and themes directory, the same FTP/SFTP notice is displayed when trying to upload or update.

How do I go about configuring the user and group permissions to provide the security hardening with the ability to upload/update within WordPress?

**Updated with per-user pool configuration settings**

Should chdir be /var/www/callkneehill.ca?

**/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d**

```
[callkneehill]
user = callkneehill
group = callkneehill

listen = /run/php/callkneehill.sock
chdir = /var/www

listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available**

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
   # SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
   SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/callkneehill.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Wordpress permissions are a bit of confusing area. I set up as per the Wordpress recommendations, and I think if you want a highly secure install Wordpress can't update itself or install plugins. If you have SSH access I can share a bash script I use that runs the Wordpress CLI nightly to updates wordpress and plugins, and a bash command I use to install plugins.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What permissions should my website files/folders have on a Linux webserver?](https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver)

Comment: @AndrewSchulman I have tried what was suggested in the **Maintained by a single user** section, but the same FTP/SFTP notice is still being displayed when trying to upload or update plugins and themes.

Answer (score 0):

The core problem might not be the file permissions, but that you are running PHP as `www-data` instead of running a PHP-FPM pool as user `callkneehill`. When you run the scripts as the same user that owns them, you don't need this kind of hacks. On a multi-user system this is also essential as it prevents the users from modifying the sites of other users.

There are several tutorials for installing PHP-FPM on Ubuntu 20.04, so there is no need to repeat the instructions here. Therefore, I only give an example on the per-user pool in `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/pool.d/callkneehill.conf`:

```
[callkneehill]
user = callkneehill
group = callkneehill

listen = /run/php/callkneehill.sock
chdir = /var/www

listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
```

Using the pool from Apache `VirtualHost` configuration is done by adding a handler that uses the UNIX socket:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$> 
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/callkneehill.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I have the installation of PHP-FPM scheduled to hopefully resolve this issue.

Comment: I have implemented PHP-FPM and used your pool code, but when I enable it, my site displays a **503** error. I have updated my question with the code from the respective files. I am new to this, so I don't know the ins and outs.

Comment: I have fixed the **503 error**, but I am still battling the permission issues for WordPress. The **callkneehill** user is still not owning the directories and files. Any ideas?