# File permissions and owner of web root

Tags: permissions, web-server

Consider you have a freshly installed Linux distro (maybe a new EC2 instance) and you are going to run a `git clone` on the `/srv` folder to host a website (maybe a PHP one).

How should you run the `git clone` so every created files and folder have the correct permission/groups? You are going to use an HTTP Server similar to Nginx to serve the website.

In this [post](https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/how-to-create-a-website-directory-and-set-up-proper-permissions/) the author has suggested this:

```
# 0. settings
web_dir=/srv/www
myusername=kassambara
# 1. Create the website directory
sudo mkdir -p $web_dir
# 2. set your user as the owner
sudo chown -R $myusername $web_dir
# 3. set the web server as the group owner
sudo chgrp -R www-data $web_dir
# 4. 755 permissions for everything
sudo chmod -R 755 $web_dir
# 5. New files and folders inherit 
# group ownership from the parent folder
chmod g+s $web_dir
```

Is this the best practice?

Comment: https://www.git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_merge

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What permissions should my website files/folders have on a Linux webserver?](https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver)