# How should I modify file permissions to accomodate Wordpress

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache2, file-permissions

I have been successfully using the method described here: [Maintained by a Single User](https://serverfault.com/a/357109/549163) and it has been working well for me.  This is my script for all my websites:

```
sudo chown -R WebAdmin /var/www/example.com/
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/example.com/
sudo chmod -R 750 /var/www/example.com/
sudo chmod g+s /var/www/example.com/
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/example.com/Uploads/
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/example.com/Uploads/
```

I maintain all the sites on that server and WebAdmin is the general user I use for FTP and also SSH.

However, I recently moved a few Wordpress sites from a hosting company to my server and the above doesn't work.  Updating Wordpress or its themes/plugins gave me the error:

> To perform the requested action, WordPress needs to access your web
> server. Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed. If you do not
> remember your credentials, you should contact your web host.

There are several "fixes" such as [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/271003/204126) which are more like workarounds and are probably insecure.  So I used the safest (AFAIK) method and made the www-data the owner of the WordPress sites, while keeping non-WordPress sites as before.  In other words, I simply ran

```
sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/wp_example.com/
```

on the WordPress sites.  This of course worked, but it becomes a pain as far as maintaining the website manually goes, because I have to login as root to do that.  I would also not be able to assign the website(s) to someone else to maintain in the future.  Note that some of my sites are hybrid (partly WordPress and part custom pages).

So I am wondering if there is a better solution that is more elegant and more general i.e. it will work for both WordPress and non-WordPress sites.

One possibility is that I add the user WebAdmin to the www-data group.  Or perhaps www-data to the WebAdmin user group?  Which makes more sense and which is more secure?

Comment: I would suggest to search a bit about POSIX ACLs: `man acl`, `man getfacl` and `man setfacl`. You can set up complex permissions, that could be inherited. Prepare the permissions on a test VM. Make sure that Wordpress is happy with them. You can have a set of premissions during the update, then revert back to a more secure set after. Add the php files into `git` source controll to monitor the changes performed by the updates.

Answer (score 4):

If both the user `WebAdmin` directly and user `www-data` through group `www-data` needs to write to these directories, the `750` is not enough. What fixes your current design would be:

```
sudo chmod -R 770 /var/www/example.com/
```

### Security considerations

However, in general this means every PHP site is running on the same user and after this modification every site could read & write the files of any other site. This means that a compromise on any of the sites compromises them all.

Using a separate user and PHP-FPM pool for every site would divide the sites into isolated compartments, mitigating this risk. You could administrate the site with the same user that is running it:

```
/var/www$ ls -l
drwxr-x--- 2 example-com www-data 4096 Aug 30 7:00 example.com
drwxr-x--- 2 example-net www-data 4096 Aug 30 7:00 example.net
drwxr-x--- 2 example-org www-data 4096 Aug 30 7:00 example.org
```

If you absolutely need the user `WebAdmin` to manage them all, you would add the user to group `www-data` and give the write permissions to the group, but I would not recommend that.

```
/var/www$ ls -l
drwxrwx--- 2 example-com www-data 4096 Aug 30 7:00 example.com
drwxrwx--- 2 example-net www-data 4096 Aug 30 7:00 example.net
drwxrwx--- 2 example-org www-data 4096 Aug 30 7:00 example.org
```

#### PHP-FPM pools

As I mentioned the PHP FPM pools, here's a short example configuration. There are several tutorials explaining these steps in detail.

1. Install PHP-FPM.
2. `/etc/php/8.2/fpm/pool.d/example-com.conf`:

   ```
   [example-com]
   user = example-com
   group = example-com

   listen = /run/php/example-com.sock
   chdir = /var/www/example.com

   listen.owner = www-data
   listen.group = www-data

   pm = dynamic
   pm.max_children = 5
   pm.start_servers = 2
   pm.min_spare_servers = 1
   pm.max_spare_servers = 3

   php_admin_value[disable_functions] = exec,passthru,shell_exec
   php_admin_flag[allow_url_fopen] = off
   php_admin_value[cgi.fix_pathinfo] = 1

   security.limit_extensions =
   ```

   The last line is decreasing the security to allow WordPress to handle SEO URLs, the others are for increasing security. The `pm` paramaters should be adjusted to your needs.
3. Enable Apache modules `mpm_event`, `proxy` & `proxy_fcgi`.
4. Add the handler to the Apache2 `<VirtualHost>` block for the site:

   ```
   <FilesMatch "\.php$">
       SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/example-com.sock|fcgi://localhost"
   </FilesMatch>
   <Proxy "fcgi://localhost/">
   </Proxy>
   ```
5. Reload or restart Apache2 & PHP-FPM services.

Comment: Changing permissions to 770 did not help with the Wordpress problem.  I get the same error.

Comment: It was a bit hacky anyway. While it gives `www-data` the permission to write to these directories, it might not be compatible with the method WordPress uses to check for the permissions. The real answer lies under the security considerations.